# Flutter error - 'Null check operator used on a null value ( The following _CastError was thrown XXXXView ) '

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm **NEW** to Flutter

I got this error when I run my flutter APP. I could not figure out why this error occurred .

**PS**: this error occurred after a navigate to another page from the bottom navigation section

[This is how the error looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsk3W.gif)

> **Error**

```
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
HomeView
```

My code in home_view.dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<HomeViewModel>(
      builder: (controller) => controller.loading.value
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: primaryColor,
            ))
          : Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // SizedBox(
                      //   height: 15,
                      //   child: CustomButton(
                      //     text: 'Sign out',
                      //     onPress: () {
                      //       FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                      //     },
                      //     color: Colors.black,
                      //   ),
                      // ),

                      _searchTextField(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      CustomText(
                        text: 'Catégory',
                        weight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      _listViewCategory(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          CustomText(
                            text: 'Meilleure vente',
                            weight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                          CustomText(
                            text: 'Voir tout',
                            fontSize: 16,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 32,
                      ),
                      _listViewProducts(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
```

code of _searchTextField()

```
  Widget _searchTextField() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

code of _listViewCategory()

```
   return GetBuilder<HomeViewModel>(
      builder: (controller) => Container(
        height: 120,
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: controller.categoryModel.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: Colors.grey.shade100),
                  height: 60,
                  width: 60,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child:
                          Image.network(controller.categoryModel[index].image)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 80,
                      child: CustomText(
                        align: Alignment.center,
                        text: controller.categoryModel[index].name,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

code _listViewProducts()

```
  Widget _listViewProducts() {
    return GetBuilder<HomeViewModel>(
        builder: (controller) => Container(
              height: 350,
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: controller.productModel.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                          child: Container(
                              height: 220,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                              child: Image.network(
                                  controller.productModel[index].image)),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        CustomText(
                          align: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          text: controller.productModel[index].name,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: CustomText(
                            text: controller.productModel[index].description,
                            align: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        CustomText(
                          text: controller.productModel[index].price + ' DH',
                          align: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: primaryColor2,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }
```

My code in control_view_model.dart

```
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/get_state_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projet_last/view/cart_view.dart';
import 'package:projet_last/view/home_view.dart';
import 'package:projet_last/view/profile_view.dart';

class ControlViewModel extends GetxController {
  int _navigatorValue = 0;

  get navigatorValue => _navigatorValue;

  Widget currentScreen = HomeView();

  void changeSelectedValue(int selectedValue) {
    _navigatorValue = selectedValue;
    switch (selectedValue) {
      case 0:
        {
          currentScreen = HomeView();
          break;
        }
      case 1:
        {
          currentScreen = CartView();
          break;
        }
      case 2:
        {
          currentScreen = ProfileView();
          break;
        }
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

My Flutter doctor output :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Comment: It means a variable is null and you used the `!` operator. Example: `int? value = null; int add = value!;` will throw this error because I used `!` on `value` while it is null. In the error it says on which line.

Comment: I inderstand but i'm not using ```!``` operator. The error is within the control_view_model.dart in case 0 ```currentScreen = HomeView();```

Comment: Always include the error message.